# JavaScript issue on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad

We have some very very basic JavaScript, on a webpage and works fine on every browser. Checked with Firebug, no issues, errors or anything.

But when we run it on an iPad ( presuming this affects other mobile devices, too ) this JS is being ignored.

Should it be doc ready or doc load?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#myshopname").blur(function()
    {
        $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').html('<img class="check" src="images/loader.gif"> Checking...').fadeIn("slow");
        $.post("user_availability.php",{ user_name:$(this).val() } ,function(data)
        {
            if(data=='no')
            {
                $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() 
                { 
                    $(this).html('oh bugger, this Shop is reserved').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
                });     
            }
            else
            {
                $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()
                {
                    $(this).html('woohoo this Shop is available').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900,1);   
                });
            }       
        });
    });
});
```

Actually the JS seems to work, it just doesnt initiate the PHP ( called via JS )

The php that the js should reference is:

```
<?php
 $existing_users=array('apple','orange','pear','nectarine','fartbag'); 
 $user_name=$_POST['user_name'];
 if (in_array($user_name, $existing_users))
 {
echo "no";
 } 
else
{
echo "yes";
}
```

?>

We will obviously connect this to db and run differently on live site, but need to get this to work clientside on all browsers and devices.

Comment: probably "blur" is not behaving as you expect on mobile safari

Comment: Does the iPad trigger the `blur()` method when you expect?   I'm guessing that because of the touch screen that perhaps it manages focus differently.

Comment: All works good, aside from the fact it doesnt trigger the php. I will post the php also.

Comment: Is your PHP on the same domain as the web page?  Most javascript requests are subject to the [same-origin-policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Yes. Although I have just tried to create a fiddle, lol. And ran into the very issue you point out. I suppose the other way to handle this is detect browser user agent, and disable the input elements.

Comment: when you call $.post, pass { user_name:$(this).val() }, you know that $(this) refers to $("#myshopname"), right?

Comment: existing_users is the array , user_name is the id within the array, myshopname is the id of the event. Not sure I understand what you are pointing out

Comment: my point is, if you are after a user_name, i find it a little strange that you are trying to get it from the value of a control with id 'myshopname'... user name = name of shop???

Comment: Its a css id still nt sure on your point, i could have called it dave.